# R: do one test for variables with pattern name "var1, var2 .... varN"

Tags: r, loops, variables, statistics

I often have to calculate things like that manually:

```
some_test(dt$some_var, dt$another_var1)
some_test(dt$some_var, dt$another_var2)
...
some_test(dt$some_var, dt$another_varN)
```

Has R a way to do it automatically if variables differ from each other only with digits in their end?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `mapply` like below

```
mapply(some_test, list(dt$some_var), dt[startsWith(names(dt),"another_var")])
```

Comment: Works excelent! Save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can create a vector of column names that you want to apply the function to and use `lapply`.

```
cols <- grep('another_var\\d+', names(dt), value = TRUE)
result <- lapply(dt[cols], function(x) some_test(dt$some_var, x))
```